# .Net 6 WebApplication won't throw BadRequestException when binding fails if ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to 'Production'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have this ASP.NET Core 6 web application project.

I have an `ErrorHandlingMiddleware` class that works fine when `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `'Development'`, because with this configuration the `BadRequestException` is thrown by the web application when binding fails.

Now, if `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `'Production'`, the web application won't throw any `BadRequestException`, but just set the response's http status code to 400.

Here's my code - `Program.cs`:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
```

`ErrorHandlingMiddleware.cs`:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        => _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
    
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            await HandleException(httpContext, exception);
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Edit: I'm using minimal apis.

Comment: Are you using a Controller?

Comment: @jdweng,  I'm working with minimum apis.

Comment: Well, It turns out I changed back to controllers.